# Finding files due to misuse linux command mv

Tags: linux, command, mv

how to find my files due to misuse mv?

for example, I change folder /var/lib/a
And I typed, "sudo mv /var/lib/b/* ./*"

then, I couldn't find my files nowhere
how can I find my files?

Answer (score -1):

When you use the mv command all the files and folders in the following list are moved to the last place in your argument list.
By using the * you are first passing all elements in the folder /var/lib/b/ as arguments for mv and afterwards all elements in the current folder ./
If you have two files b1,b2 in /var/lib/b/ and two folders f1,f2 in ./ your command would be expanded to

```
mv /var/lib/b/b1 /var/lib/b/b2 ./f1 ./f2
```

That would mean all your files b1 and b2 should be moved to ./f2 now together with ./f1

Comment: thxs for your answer.
I finally found files in  Temporary Items.

Comment: I hope it was helpful to solve your case, that much later.